# adding between two column by usin VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I would like know how i can add 1st column with 2nd columns by VBA , example when someone click on a button.Then,the sum are fill back in 1st columns...and automatic continue for 10 r0ws.
this are my coding

---

```
Sub Button1_Click()

For Each r In Range("B1:B10")

For Each a In Range("A1:A110")

a.Value = a.Value + r.Value

Next a

Next r

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code just sum all values in `Range(B1:B10)` to each value in `Range("A1:A10"`

There is no need to loop twice. You can use this code instead:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim A As Range

For Each A In Range("A1:A10")
    A.Value = A.Value + Range("B" & A.Row).Value
Next A

End Sub
```

It will take each cell of `Range ("A1:A10")` and will sum it with the value of the adjacent cell in column B. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks 4 ur answer..But what the function of Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum?

Comment: I understood you where asking how to sum

Comment: but i still get the value in 1st column are adding with sum of value in 2nd column...

Comment: In your question, you say *I would like know how i can add 1st column with 2nd columns by VBA* and that's what you have. What do you want exactly. You need to explain better

Comment: sorry for my mistake in asking question..actually,i want add 1st column and 2nd column by row..means that 1st row in column 1 adding with 1st row in column 2 then the answer are show in 1st row of column 1...then it continues until row 10...tq

Comment: @MuhdMunzir Check code updated. Now the code just sums `A1+B1`, `A2+B2`, `A3+B3` and so on, until row 10. The result of the sum is shown in column A in each row. Is this what you wanted?

Comment: yes the result are shown in column A for each row..new.value of A1= A1 + B1,tq

Comment: Glad to help. Please, mark the answer as correct, so the question will appear as resolved.